# Why would calling the super class `__getattribute__` cause an infinite recursion?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, overriding, getattribute

clearly the following will result in an infinite loop:

```
class Klaus:
    def __getattribute__(self, key):
        return getattr(type(self), key)
```

However, I don't see why calling the super class `__getattribute__` would:

```
class Parent:

    def __init__(self):
        print("begin __init__")
        self._x = 3
        print("end __init__")

    def __getattribute__(self, attr_name):
        superk = super(type(self), self)
        boohl = superk.__getattribute__ == self.__getattribute__
        print("with age comes wisdom", boohl)
        return superk.__getattribute__(attr_name)

class Child(Parent):

    def __getattribute__(self, attr_name):
        superk = super(type(self), self)
        boohl = superk.__getattribute__ == self.__getattribute__
        print("this booger is green!", boohl)
        return super(type(self), self).__getattribute__(attr_name)

obj = Child()
print("lambda")
print(obj._x)
print("anonymous")
```

Comment: *"clearly the following will result in an infinite loop"* No it won't? And it's not relevant to your question anyway, is it?

Answer (score 1):

Because `type(self)` is *always* Child. Even though you're in a method of Parent, `self` is still an instance of Child.

This is why when you use the long form of `super` you must always explicitly use the current class, rather than this. Of course, in Python 3 you can use `super()` without any parameters anyway.

Comment: I don't see how the result of `type(self)` is relevant here. The problem is the `self.__getattribute__` part, isn't it?

Comment: @Aran-Fey: There are at least two bugs, the one you're looking at and the one Daniel is looking at. Either is sufficient to cause infinite recursion.

Comment: In other words, it is always wrong to do `super(type(self), self)`. It should be either explicit `super(Parent, self)`, `super(Child, self)`, or implicit `super()`.